# «Отходы из пластика» — грамотно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, предлоги, словосочетания

***Отходы из пластика*** составили более 90% от общего объема мусора, поступающего по реке Пирита и ручью Мустйыэ в Балтийское море. На пляже Штромка в Пыхья-Таллинне было обнаружено большое количество пакетов, бутылок, крышек, окурков и других предметов из пластика.
А. Тараскин. Пластик наносит удар в спину. МК-Эстония, 28.11.2018

Не могу объяснить почему, но не нравится мне это сочетание: *отходы **из** пластика*.
А как вы считаете — правильно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 2):

Я готов *допустить* такое выражение как сокращение от "*отходы, состоящие из пластика*".

Трудно подобрать короткое выражение, которое звучало бы убедительно. Например, выражение "отходы пластика" уместно по отношению к производственным отходам предприятия, выпускающего продукцию "из пластика" (понятие "пластик/и/" - тоже условность, поскольку оно абстрактно обобщает разнообразные материалы). В данном случае речь идёт о бытовых отходах в виде использованных упаковок (полиэтиленовые пакеты, поликоровые бутылки, целлофановая плёнка и пр.), и "*отходами пластика*" этот бытовой мусор нельзя назвать (люди используют не "пластик" как таковой, а продукцию в упаковке).

Comment: Извините за бестолковость, но **поликоровый** – это какой?

Comment: Поликор - материал, из которого делаются компакт-диски; вероятно, из тонкого листа штампуются и некоторые виды упаковки.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать: **Пластиковые бытовые отходы составили более 90% от общего объема мусора...**

**Информация**

**Отхо́ды** — вещества или предметы, которые образованы в процессе производства, выполнения работ, оказания услуг или в процессе потребления, которые удаляются, предназначены для удаления или подлежат удалению.[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Отходы#Раздельный_сбор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80)

**Твёрдые бытовые отходы** (ТБО, бытовой мусор) — предметы или товары, потерявшие потребительские свойства, наибольшая часть отходов потребления.

**Твёрдые бытовые отходы** представляют собой сложную гетерогенную смесь. ТБО в настоящее время состоят из следующих компонентов: **биологические отходы, бумага, древесина, стекло, пластмассы и др.**

Comment: Наверно, надо править: 1. _Поэтому это не отходы **их** пластика..._ 2. _бытовой мусор (небиологические ТО искусственного или естественного происхождения) **[1]** — ?   3. _а последний часто на бытовом уровне **именуются** просто мусором._ 4. _ТБО в настоящее время **состоит** из следующих..._

Comment: Мне понравился Ваш ответ – я его, конечно, оценила. Но мне все-таки кажется, что правильно _ТБО состоят._

Comment: Да, состоят. Я просто не заметила неправильную запись.

Answer (score 1):

«Отходы из пластика» — изделия из пластика или их части, ставшие отходами. Мне кажется,
такая форма (отходы из..) приемлема.

> Такие полимеры могут повторно обрабатываться, что позволяет перерабатывать бытовые и производственные **отходы из** термопластов в новые изделия. [Федор Лобанов. Разобрали по волокнам // «Русский репортер», 2014]
>
> Драгоценные металлы и сплавы, лом и **отходы из** них, алмазное сырье, драгоценные, полудрагоценные, синтетические и искусственные камни и изделия из них устанавливаются по решению правительства РСФСР [С. Разин. Павлов в неволе, цены ― на свободе // «Комсомольская правда», 1991]

Хотя, строго говоря, корректно писать "пластиковые отходы":

> В 2002 г. правительство области учредило конкурс на лучший проект по использованию пластиковых отходов. [Николай Малетин. Потребительская корзина для мусора (2003) // «Деловой квартал» (Екатеринбург), 2003.02.10]
>
> Пока ученые не могут объяснить, почему уровень загрязнения океана пластиковыми отходами остается неизменным. [Природа вокруг нас // «Знание - сила», 2011]

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что лучше звучит вариант **"пластиковые отходы"**.
Хотя, конечно, еще уместнее говорить о **пластиковом мусоре**. Но так как дальше по тексту слово *"мусор"* применяется еще раз, то все-таки **"пластиковые отходы"**.

Answer (score 0):

**Отходы из пластика?**

Выражение кажется не очень корректным, но ведь есть **изделия из пластика**. Если это изделие больше не используется, его относят к отходам, но оно по-прежнему сделано из пластика.

Из словаря:

ОТХОДЫ, -ов; мн. (ед. отход, -а; м.). Остатки какого-л. производства; отбросы. О. нефтяной промышленности. Жидкие, твёрдые о. Бытовые о.

Может быть, в словарную статью следует добавить "твердые бытовые **отходы из стекла, дерева, пластика".**

**Отходы** – это или **материалы**, которые остались от производства, или использованные изделия, которые также сделаны из какого-то **материала**. Поэтому **возникает потребность указать материал этих отходов.**

Сравнить: деревянная шкатулка – шкатулка из дерева, бронзовый подсвечник – подсвечник из бронзы. По аналогии можно сказать: пластиковые отходы – отходы из пластика.

Пластиковые отходы – корректное выражение, но его **не во всех конструкциях удобно использовать.** Поэтому нет особых причин считать некорректным сочетание ***отходы из пластика***, это просто указание материала